# Assigning a value to a cell in PHP Macro (Excel)

Tags: php, vba, excel

I'm trying to assign the value `=FALSE` to a cell in Excel using a "Button". The macro for the button is the following:

```
function_TEST_Click(){

Sheet("Sheet1").Range("J5").Value="=FALSE"

}
```

When I click the button I get the following error:

> Error in PHP macro.
>
> Code: M0 - PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in Module1 on line 3

Could you guys let me know what am I doing wrong? Please have in mind that this is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm not familiar with Excel VBA, neither with PHP Macros.

Comment: You can't use VBA code within a PHP function (or do you use some 3rd party libraries, if so which one?). VBA and PHP are 2 completely different languages, that can't work. You need a better/wider explanation what you are trying to do at all, because you are doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Value expects a value, you're trying to enter a formula. Either

```
 Sheet("Sheet1").Range("J5").Value= FALSE
```

or

`Sheet("Sheet1").Range("J5").Formula ="=FALSE"`

Comment: That's just wrong! `Sheet("Sheet1").Range("J5").Value="=FALSE"` ***does*** work in pure VBA just try it yourself.